# Combine multiple search result Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to filter my data using First name  , mobile number  by one input field like material dataTable filter.
constructor:

```
  constructor() {
            this.filteredPatient = this.patientsearch.valueChanges
              .pipe(
                startWith(''),
                map(p => p ? this._filterPatient(p) : this.patients.slice())
                    );
          }



    private _filterPatient(value: string): IPatient[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    const searchByfirstName = this.patients.filter(p => p.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    const searchBylastName = this.patients.filter(p => p.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    const searchBymobileNumber = this.patients.filter(p => p.mobileNumber.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    const mergedObj = { ...searchByfirstName, ...searchBymobileNumber };
    return mergedObj;
  }
```

but this is not working . Can anyone suggest me how can I filter data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that like the following:

```
private _filterPatient(value: string): IPatient[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

  const result = this.patients.filter(
    (p) =>
      p.firstName?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
      p.lastName?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
      p.mobileNumber?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
  );

  return result;
}
```